# Ionic app covers iPhone status bar in iOS 9.1

Tags: ios, angularjs, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Let me first start by saying this project is the first time working with an ionic app. When we were testing the application on iPhones running iOS below 9 we hadn't encountered this problem. We recently transferred ownership to the company's repo. After using cordova to compile and loading the application to iPhones running 9.1 every screen now overlaps the status bar.

[image]

The following warnings are present when running the app in xcode:

[image]

Has anyone else encountered this issues recently? Any help would be most appreciated.

Thank you,

Griffin

xcode warnings

Comment: are you sure that doesn't happen on previous versions? do you have the statusbar plugins installed?

Comment: I'm certain it didn't happen on previous versions. I just took over the project. Strangely the statusbar plugin wasn't present. I just added the plugin it helped a bit but it is still an issue. I appreciate your assistance. I'll be focused on patching for 9's https requirements.

Comment: I didn't say happened, I say happen, right now, the same version of the app but on other iOS versions

Comment: found this resource: http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ionic-app-development-tips-tricks/       .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .search-bar {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Install cordova-plugin-statusbar

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar

Turn StatusBarOverlaysWebView to false

> preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />